# MSBVAR package installation error

Tags: r

I try to install the R MSBVAR-package v. 0.9-3 manually on my Windows system.
After installing all packages which are needed by the MSBVAR package I installed Rtools, but I still get an error message which I do not understand.

```
* installing *source* package 'MSBVAR' ...
** package 'MSBVAR' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/Program Files (x86)/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c A0_W.cpp -o A0_W.o
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c A0_W.cpp -o A0_W.o'
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:215: A0_W.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'MSBVAR'
* removing 'C:/Users/dbaerradoaca/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/MSBVAR'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘C:/Users/db/Desktop/MSBVAR_0.9-3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Hope you can help me

Denis